# Implementing matrix columns as array like objects

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays, square-bracket

I am trying to implement a Matrix class in Javascript, using a single `Float64Array` to store the elements. The rows are again `Float64Array` objects that share the data's `ArrayBuffer`. Here is a simple implementation so far:

```
class Matrix {

  constructor(n = 3, m = 3, i) {
    this.n = n;
    this.m = m:
    let data = new Float64Array(m * n);
    if (i) {
      data.fill(i);
    }
    this.data_ = data;
    let rows = new Array(n);
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      rows[i] = new Float64Array(this.data_.buffer, 8 * i * m, m);
    }
    this.rows_ = rows;
  }

  getRow(i) {
    return this.rows_[i];
  }

}
```

This is all great, all changes to a row are reflected in the `data` and vice versa.

But I am struggling to find an elegant solution for the columns. Just like a row each column should be an array like object that can be accessed with square brackets and reflects the changes in the underlying `data`. So for the n-th column`colN[i]` should get and set the value at `data[i * colCount + n]`.

Is there a way to somehow map the `ArrayBuffer` to a `TypedArray`, so the `TypedArray` does not simply access one continuous sequence of the `ArrayBuffer`?

Or is there another approach (maybe by somehow overriding the square bracket getter and setter)?

Comment: No, a `TypedArray` always represents a continuous slice of the buffer data.

Comment: Yes, your `getColumn()` function could return an object with custom setters and getters. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: I just found this library and will investigate how they do it; https://github.com/munrocket/overload-bracket